# ClassNotFoundException when running in Command Prompt

Tags: java

I am very new to java and tried to run a simple code of calculating volume. The code is below:

```
package chapter6;

class Box {

    double width;
    double height;
    double depth;
}
```

---

```
package chapter6;

    public class BoxDemo {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Box myBox = new Box();
            double vol;

            myBox.depth = 1;
            myBox.height = 2;
            myBox.width = 3;

            vol = myBox.depth * myBox.height * myBox.width ;        

            System.out.println("Volume: " + vol);
        }

    }
```

---

I am able to run the code from eclipse, but when i try to run the code in Command Prompt i get the error:

```
C:\Prabhjot\Java\CompleteRefence\build\classes>java BoxDemo.class
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: BoxDemo/class
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: BoxDemo.class
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
Could not find the main class: BoxDemo.class.  Program will exit.
```

Please assist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have put your class in a package called `chapter6`. This means that the java file should be in a folder called `chapter6` in the class root folder of your project. And when you run it, you should be in the root folder and use the command `java chapter6.BoxDemo`

Comment: thanks, now i got it. I was doing a mistake of using the command from C:\Prabhjot\Java\CompleteRefence\build\classes\chapter6 which shaould have been the way u mentioned. thanks!!

Answer (score 13):

First class file should be at this location:

```
C:\Prabhjot\Java\CompleteRefence\build\classes\chapter6\BoxDemo.class
```

Then you should be inside:

```
C:\Prabhjot\Java\CompleteRefence\build\classes>
```

Then issue the command:

```
java chapter6.BoxDemo
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
C:\Prabhjot\Java\CompleteRefence\build\classes>java chapter6.BoxDemo (RUN)
```

There is no need to specify .class extinction to the file while running.After compiling the java file it will create the .class file.

[**EXAMPLE**](http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/javaindos.html)

Comment: the problem above is my code is in package, pls see: package chapter6;

Comment: No need for the `-d` in this example, and your package name is "wrong", but other than that, it's correct now.

Comment: Great! I'm not able to undo the vote though, because both my comments crossed your edits...

Answer (score 1):

There is mistake in how you are running your program from console.

You are doing

`java BoxDemo.class`

But you need to do only

`java BoxDemo`

While running your program you don't need to mention **.class** with the name.

and if you are accessing it from root folder then you need to do

`java chapter6.BoxDemo`

Answer (score 0):

When you invoke `BoxDemo.class`, Java looks for a class called `class` in the `BoxDemo` package, which doesn't exist. As you can see from the output `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: BoxDemo/class`, it's searching for a directory `BoxDemo`.

Instead, just specify the class name: `BoxDemo`; e.g. `java BoxDemo`.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted, as this provides the _exact same answer_ as above, just with more info.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your example won't work, since the package name is not correct.